# c# DateTime object error

Tags: c#

I trying to create a DateTime object. I get my values from a string array.

When i run the code, the exact date time is printed as : 2009-12-21 06:07:05

```
string tmpDate = values[0].Trim() +" "+ values[1].Trim();

Console.WriteLine(tmpDate);

DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
```

For some reason i get a DateTime format exception for this?
Any ide´s?

Best regards
Marthin

Comment: Unable to reproduce your error. Do you receive the same exception if you hardcode "2009-12-21 06:07:05" into that method?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me in linqpad using the data you provided.

Comment: Its been solved now. The problem lay in a function call after the last row where i tried to send the DateTime object to a function that didnt except it. The confusing part was the exception from .net that said that the string was entered in a faulty way which is was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When things that obviously should work don't work then assume there's something you cannot see.  Like this:

```
        string[] values = new string[] { "2009-12-21\0", "06:07:05" };
        string tmpDate = values[0].Trim() + " " + values[1].Trim();
        Console.WriteLine(tmpDate);
        DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(tmpDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying something other than null for the 3rd parameter (needs to implement [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)). Since it rarely matters in the applications I build, I often use [DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.invariantinfo.aspx) or [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).